# Connecting a Mosquitto MQTT C client to Azure IoT-hub

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto, azure-iot-hub

As the title states, I'm having difficulties connecting my Mosquitto MQTT client (written in C) to my Azure IoT-hub. I've managed to connect to many different platforms before (e.g. Amazon EC2, ThingsBoard, TheThings.io, SierraWireless, ...), so I know my client is pretty solid.

The difficulty here is the fact that I need some sort of certificate to be allowed to connect, and I'm not sure what I need to do this.

I have added the following configuration in order to get this working:

```
mosquitto_opts_set(client, MOSQ_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, "MQTT_PROTOCOL_V311");
mosquitto_tls_set(client, "/home/ca-certificates.crt", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
mosquitto_tls_insecure_set(client, 1);
mosquitto_tls_opts_set(client, 0, "tlsv1", NULL);
mosquitto_username_pw_set(client, "hubname.azure-devices.net/deviceName", "SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=hubname.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FdeviceName&sig=sigValue&se=1553087157");
```

In the code above, "hubname", "deviceName" and "sigValue" are of course replaced with real values in my code.

Can any of you point me to what I'm doing wrong, or what other configuration steps I need to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get things working. It turned out I had cross-compiled my Mosquitto client without SSL support. So after compiling and installing again, these functions now all return 1 and I can connect successfully.

```
mosquitto_opts_set(client, MOSQ_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, "MQTT_PROTOCOL_V311");
mosquitto_tls_set(client, NULL, /etc/ssl/certs, NULL, NULL, NULL);
mosquitto_tls_insecure_set(client, 1);
mosquitto_tls_opts_set(client, 0, "tlsv1", NULL);
mosquitto_username_pw_set(client, "hubname.azure-devices.net/deviceName", "SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=hubname.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FdeviceName&sig=sigValue&se=1553087157");
```

Comment: In the meantime Microsoft released some source code on Github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/IoTMQTTSample

Answer (score 0):

I install [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/download/) on Windows and send a message with the command successfully:

```
mosquitto_pub -d -h hubname.azure-devices.net -i "device1" -u "hubname.azure-devices.net/device1" -P "SharedAccessSignature sr=hubname.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fdevice1&sig=sig&se=1553325061" -m "hi from mosquitto client" -t "devices/device1/messages/events/" -p 8883 --cafile \path-to-cert-file\IoTHubTest.cer -V mqttv311
```

Based on information you provided, maybe the issue caused by the certificate.

Azure IoT Hub use DigiCert Baltimore Root certificate to secure device connection. (**Note that China Azure didn’t use CyberTrust Root CA. Instead it still uses WoSign Root CA.**)

> You can create this file by copying the certificate information from
>   [certs.c](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/certs/certs.c) in the Azure IoT SDK for C. Include the lines -----BEGIN
>   CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----, remove the " marks at
>   the beginning and end of every line, and remove the \r\n characters at
>   the end of every line.

Here I save it as IoTHubTest.cer.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: I tried this method but i receive these messages :-
Client DiscoverTest4 sending CONNECT
Client DiscoverTest4 received CONNACK (5)
Connection Refused: not authorised.

Comment: @Sanyamkoul Post a new question and describe what you did and your settings like what's kind of authentication method device you have registered on Azure IoT Hub etc. I believe someone will help you.